# How to use this cache for python requirements caching ? Will this cachetask works if we use Hosted Agent for build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, npm-cache, pipeline-cache

How to use this cache for python requirements caching ?
Will this cache task works if we use Hosted Agent for build

Comment: Hi Did you check out below solution. How did it go?

Answer (score 1):

In [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#pythonpip) you have examples how to use cahce with `requirements.txt` file.

```yaml
variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.pip

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'python | "$(Agent.OS)" | requirements.txt'
    restoreKeys: | 
      python | "$(Agent.OS)"
      python
    path: $(PIP_CACHE_DIR)
  displayName: Cache pip packages

- script: pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And `Pipefile.lock`:

```
variables:
  PIPENV_CACHE_DIR: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.pipenv

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'python | "$(Agent.OS)" | Pipfile.lock'
    restoreKeys: | 
      python | "$(Agent.OS)"
      python
    path: $(PIPENV_CACHE_DIR)
  displayName: Cache pipenv packages

- script: pipenv install
```

Taks should run without any issue on Self Hosted Agents if you have all prerequisites installed:

[image]

What is worth to mention this doesn't work with Azure DevOps Server.